# Prove that $f$ is an Affine function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

### Definition:

An affine function is a function composed of a linear function + a constant and its graph is a straight line.

---

A topological space $X$ is said to be disconnected if it is the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets. Otherwise, $X$ is said to be connected.

---

### Question:

> Assume that $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a connected set and $f : U
>  \to \mathbb R^m$ is a function such that we have $\forall x \in U
>  \quad Df(x)=A$   Such that $A: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is a
>   linear transformation.
>
> Prove that $f$ is an Affine function.

---

Note:

We just know that the derivative is a linear transformation. I know that its like the case of working with normal derivaties in $\mathbb R$. But, It's not the same. I can't for example do integration! Any idea on reaching the statement?  (Please include more details so that i can understand it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any affine function can be written in the form $f(x)=Mx+b$, where in your case $M$ is $m\times n$, and $b$ is $1\times m$. If this is not your starting point, then you can easily prove this. Writing $f(x)=T(x)+b$, where $T$ is linear. Then $f_j(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i T_j(e_i)+b$, where $e_i$ is the standard basis of $R^n$. This can clearly be rewritten in the form $f(x)=Mx+b$ using the rules of matrix multiplication, with $M_{ij}=T_j(e_i)$.

Then in general, the result follows from the [Gradient Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem). You can do this by defining $g_i(x):=f_i(x)$, so that $g_i(x)$ maps $R^n$ to $R$ and performing an integration, where you are guaranteed to find a path connecting two points by the connectedness of $U$. This will show that $g_i(x)$ is linear for each $i$, so that $f$ is affine.

Comment: Can u prove it without using that theorem?